# Save custom view's state?

Tags: android, view, save, viewstate, state

I have an application where a user taps on the screen (in which a custom view is in place with a canvas) and a bitmap appears where the user taps. My application runs fine, except when i press the 'home' button and leave the activity. This is an example of how it looks when the user taps on the screen and places the bitmaps (before the home button is pressed): https://i.stack.imgur.com/6BgIL.png

When the user presses the 'home' button and then returns to the app, it stops working properly. The bitmap grid that is placed in the background disappears, as well as all other bitmap balls that were painted onto the canvas. The only remaining ball is the ball that was last placed. Not only this, but the activity freezes and only allows the user to press any button after a few seconds. This is how the screen looks after the user presses 'home' button and returns to the activity (same screen as above picture): https://i.stack.imgur.com/198bP.png

How do I save the custom view's state so that when the activity is started again, it remains the same? (or if i'm not approaching this problem correctly, are there any other ways to fix it?). Here is my code for the pause and resume method in my custom surface view:

```
public void pause(){
    isRunning = false;
    while(true){
        try {
            ourThread.join();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        break;
    }
    ourThread = null;
}

public void resume(){
    isRunning = true;
    ourThread = new Thread(this);
    ourThread.start();

}
```

I've been searching for a while, but I can't seem to find a solution. Other code will be provided if needed. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Refer to this http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html

you would need to use onResume() to draw the view on screen...

read  the actiivty lifecycle there and find out the actual reason behind the complete view not showing in second screen...you might had to restructure your activity code a bit for this..

Comment: How would I draw the same view on the screen again without drawing a new view? I want to keep the same balls and grid that were on the view before

Comment: Some of the view is missing in second screen(but not all), means you must have some code working in onStart() or onResume() methods,,you would need to look at it... onCreate() will be called first/single time the activity starts.. while onStart() and onResume() will be called **again**  when user presses home button and returns back to app... you would have to look out for actually the reason why some of the view is missing(by keeping activity lifecycle in mind), then you can work out for your problem...

Comment: I'll provide my code for resume and pause methods in an edit in the original post. I can't seem to find any problems, maybe you could help?

Answer (score 0):

you need to save all required data on onPause(), such as balls coordinates and activity states and then restore everything on onResume().

you can store and restore any Java object. 
read more about onRetainNonConfigurationInstance() and getLastNonConfigurationInstance() at http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html

Comment: This is a problem because once the ball is placed, it's coordinates are deleted. As soon as the user taps on the screen to place another ball, the coordinates are overwritten by the new ball's coordinates.